# How to add coeficient to linear model

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, r-raster, gstat

I want to manually set a coefficient for a variable that is not input in my linear model so that I can perform a spatial prediction.

I'm going to try to expose my question in the most simple and clear way.
What I have:

- a raster stack with 4 binary variables for soil cover: `agro`, `open`,
  `tran` and `urb`
- a linear model `lm(formula = no2 ~ open + tran + urb, data = df)`

The reason why I only used 3 of the variables in my linear ways to prevent multicollinearity in the model, because they are proportions of land coverage that add up to 100%.

So, my goal is to add a coefficient to my model for the `agro` variable, so that all of the 4 variables are used correctly in `raster::predict()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the offset term in the formula and include the desired coefficient and variable therein:

```
lm(formula = no2 ~ open + tran + urb + offset(agro*400), data = df)
```

So this is regressing `formula` on `open, tran and urb` plus the fixed term `agro * 400`. For more than one given coefficient, add the appropriate additional offset() terms.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the collinearity by leaving the intercept out of your model.  Use

```
lm(formula = no2 ~ open + tran + urb + agro - 1, data = df)
```

and you'll be able to estimate coefficients for all of the predictors (but no intercept term).